# Get Particular value from Json Using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get only name value from below Json using Javscript or Jquery.

From below json I need to get key **name** values-Automation1, Automation2, Automation3

```js
{
  "status": [
    [{
      "id": 3,
      "orgId": 1,
      "name": "Automation1",
      "email": "",
      "Url": "",
      "memberCount": 101,
      "permission": 0
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "orgId": 1,
      "name": "Automation2",
      "email": "",
      "Url": "",
      "memberCount": 13,
      "permission": 0
    }, {
      "id": 12,
      "orgId": 1,
      "name": "Automation3",
      "email": "",
      "Url": "/",
      "memberCount": 25,
      "permission": 0
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: `data.status.map(s => s.name)`?

Comment: Loop over `status[0]` and retrieve them. Also note that the structure you've got there is an object, not JSON.

Comment: jQuery doesn’t deal with JSON. Use JSON.parse to convert it into an object.

Comment: Possibly a typo in the question, but for some reason your status has two `[` `]` making it an array inside an array, so taking @slideshowp2 comment, it would be: `data.status[0].map(s=>s.name)`  https://jsfiddle.net/3ed1gucv/

Comment: yes Thanks.Fiddle It is working.But I am trying below. I am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"
       var data = result;
console.log(data.response[0].map(s=>s.name))

Comment: here result is Json data.

Comment: Now it is working .I have tried below.

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(result);
console.log(data.response[0].map(s=>s.name))